# firebug display network error

Tags: error-handling, firebug

I searched in google but couldn't get a solution.

When I working on my project now firebug show 4 errors something like this.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/LankaInstitute/images/profile.jpg"

profile.jpg

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/LankaInstitute/images/premium-%20tag.png"

premium- tag.png

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/LankaInstitute/images/profile.jpg"

profile.jpg

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/LankaInstitute/images/premium-%20tag.png"

premium- tag.png

"CSS Usage: initializing extensions"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/LankaInstitute/images/profile.jpg"

profile.jpg

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/LankaInstitute/images/premium-%20tag.png"

premium- tag.png

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/LankaInstitute/images/profile.jpg"

profile.jpg

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/LankaInstitute/images/premium-%20tag.png"

premium- tag.png

"CSS Usage: initializing extensions"

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/LankaInstitute/images/premium-%20tag.png"

premium- tag.png

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/LankaInstitute/images/profile.jpg"
```

Can anybody tell me what does this mean and how can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: confirm if the files exsist on the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server but the server could not find what was requested. 404 errors should not be confused with "server not found" or similar errors, in which a connection to the destination server could not be made at all. Another similar error is "410: Gone", which indicates that the requested resource has been intentionally removed and will not be available again. A 404 error indicates that the requested resource may be available in the future.
When communicating via HTTP, a server is required to respond to a request, such as a web browser's request for an HTML document (web page), with a numeric response code and an optional, mandatory, or disallowed (based upon the status code) message. In the code 404, the first "4" indicates a client error, such as a mistyped URL. The following two digits indicate the specific error encountered. HTTP's use of three-digit codes is similar to the use of such codes in earlier protocols such as FTP and NNTP.

*you can find out how to fix the error at [here](http://www.prestashop.com/blog/en/404-not-found-error-how-to-fix-it/) also please check for the png images wheteher they are in corrct folder or not*

Comment: thanks for response. I am not using a file named profile.jpg in my project.