# How to disable NetworkError from console errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using firebug, whenever I run my project on the localhost, I don't have all the pictures so I get 700-1000 errors:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - images/products/tiny_110-01-217-02.jpg"
```

As this is very annoying, I would like to ask how to disable NetworkError from console errors?

Comment: This is an entirely different question than when it started! Just ask a new question. The posted answer makes no sense now, because it's answering the old question.

Comment: Did you changed your question? The first answer is sooo unrelated.

Comment: @Vova Potapov This is a different question altogether. Please ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NetworkError clean picture that don't exist from you project

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492800/firebug-display-network-error) and this [link](http://www.fixerrorcodesnow.com/error-404)

Otherwise, please try the following. It works for me though.

1. Check for errors in the URL. Often times the 404 Not Found error appears because the URL was typed wrong or the link that was clicked on points to the wrong URL.
2. Clear your browser's cache if you have any indication that the 404 Not Found message might just be yours. For example, if you can reach the URL from your phone but not from your tablet, clearing the cache on your tablet's browser might help.

Comment: I know how to fix it it not real error because i don't have that all pictures on my pc in website all works because they on the server ,i just don't want too see that all error in my visual2012 i trying to find the way to disable error that came from NetworkError,disable i mean Not to fix just not to show them